# Not able to add todo in a todo-list using react and redux. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
   render() {
    const listItems = this.props.todos.map((todo) =>
      <ListItem key={todo.id} id={todo.id} content={todo.content} onEdit={this.onEditItem}/>
    )
    return <>
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {listItems}
      </ul>
      {/* <AddItem/> */}
      <div className="add-item">
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeValue}/>
        <button type="submit" onClick={this.onAddItem}>Add Item</button>
      </div>
    </>
  }
```

```js
onAddItem = () => {
    this.props.submitNewTodo({ id: this.props.todos.length + 1, content: this.state.value})
    };
```

When I console.log `this.props.todos.length` it returns the value 2 and `this.state.value` returns the value typed into the input. But the "Add Item" button doesn't work.

I have mapped `submitNewTodo` to dispatch `addTodo(newTodo)` like so

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    submitNewTodo: function(newTodo) {
      dispatch(addTodo(newTodo));
    }
  }
}
```

Complete code is in this codepen.

https://codepen.io/blenderous/pen/MWjdyoN?editors=0011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addTodo` action creator is wrong:

```js
const addTodo = (todo) => {
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  todo
};
```

this is a method that treats

```js
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  todo
```

as a method body. (`type` being used as the break label for the string `'ADD_TODO'`, followed by `todo`)

If you want to return an action, these two notations are correct:

```js
const addTodo = (todo) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    todo
  }
};
// note the parantheses!
const addTodo = (todo) => ({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  todo
});
```

Comment: Also, general observation: this is a very old style of redux, if you are learning redux right now, you might be following a very old tutorial stat teaches you a style of redux that will end up being a multitude longer than actually required. Please follow the official tutorials: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice with your code is that your reducer is not following the pattern Redux uses.

```
const todoReducer = ( state = [{ id: 1, content: "Call Client" },
       { id: 2, content: "Write Log" }], action ) => {
  if (action.type == ADD_TODO) {
    return state.concat(action.todo);
  }
  else {
    return state;
  }
}
```

The first rule that it breaks is that this should be a switch, not an if statement.

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'ADD_TODO':
    // create new todos with the added todo
    const newTodos = [
      ...state.todos,
      action.payload.todo,
    ]
    
    // new state object
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: newTodos,
    }

  default:
    return {
      ...state,
    }

}
```

The second rule is that you want to always have a payload property to follow the proper flux patterns. That payload would contain all of your data.

```
const addTodo = (todo) => {
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  payload: {
    todo,
  }
};
```

Comment: I have already used the connect Component from react-redux like so `const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Presentational);`

Comment: you can view the entire code of my app here: https://codepen.io/blenderous/pen/MWjdyoN?editors=0011

Comment: Hi, random redux maintainer here. Just to clear this up: switch may be convention (and only in old styles of redux, [modern redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) is very different in general), but definitely not a fixed rule.
Same goes for a payload property. It's not a necessity, only convention.

Comment: Fair enough, I suppose it isn't going to stop the code from compiling, but it definitely make debugging much easier.